# MeteorJS v 1.3 to Heroku error

Tags: meteor, heroku

I want to deploy `Meteor` to `heroku` but have problems with starting the app.

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/kevinseguin/heroku-buildpack-meteor)

In heroku `logs -t` this results in:

```
2016-04-25T13:20:44.434043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
crashed to starting 2016-04-25T13:20:48.587122+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node
.meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js` 2016-04-25T13:21:49.118920+00:00
heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind 
to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch 2016-04-25T13:21:49.118920+00:00
heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2016-04-25T13:21:50.240617+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
status 137 2016-04-25T13:21:50.250147+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
changed from starting to crashed 2016-04-25T13:21:51.781162+00:00
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
path="/" host=pcmaster.herokuapp.com
request_id=99d374ee-cd1d-460f-b2bc-ef867dca219f fwd="217.196.169.249"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 

2016-04-25T13:21:53.057121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=pcmaster.herokuapp.com  
request_id=43cb523f-0036-4af8-b6d6-6db4c883f2b2 fwd="217.196.169.249" 
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What do I need to do differently?

Thanks